# How do I give Symfony templates a CSS class based on their navigation path

Tags: php, templates, symfony1

I am trying to render templates in Symfony with a CSS class to denote which part of the site they belong to.  For example: I am in `/games` I'd like the page to look something like:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="games">
<!-- content -->
</div>
```

Or if we are displaying `/home/profile` the page would look like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="home">
<!-- content -->
</div>
```

Basically I am looking for a similar functionality to CodeIgniter's url segment methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the class simply the name of the module? If it is, do this:

```
<div class="<?php echo $sf_context->getModuleName() ?>">
```

You could also set it as a parameter on the request by defining it in your routes:

```
page:
  url: /page
  param: { module: default, action: page, section: games }
  ...
```

Then get it off the request in your template:

```
<div class="<?php echo $sf_request['section'] ?>">
```

Finally, if it's the same for each module but not equivalent to the module name, you could set it in `preExecute`:

```
public function preExecute()
{
  $this->getRequest()->setParameter('section', 'workouts');
}
```

Comment: The module name solution is pretty much perfect.  It would be even more perfect if I could put it in the layout instead of template but I don't think '$sf_context' is available to the layout.  I just don't want to have to repeat this everywhere when it really seems better to put it just once in the layout.

Comment: $sf_context is available in layouts. Also, it should be "getModuleName" not "getModule"

Comment: Ah!  My mistake, all works perfectly now - thanks for the insight.